# Replace all divs with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#select_albums').load(document.location.href + "&action=get_albums");
```

But this is only replacing only the first found div with the id #select_albums from DOM. How do I replace all divs with an id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every item in the DOM has a unique id. If you want to act on many divs at the same time use a class `$(".myclass")` or a tag `$("div")` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because by definition an element ID can only appear once on a page. If you have more elements use a class instead.

```
$('.select_albums').load(document.location.href + "&action=get_albums");
```

With

```
<div class="select_albums"></div>
<div class="select_albums"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

id's must be unique, try using a class instead such as $(".albums").load...

Answer (score 1):

[`id`s must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)